# Constrain new window opened from a <webview>

Tags: webview, electron

When `window.open()` is called from code running inside a `<webview>`, the opened window itself seems to be a more privileged window, its contents are not inside a `<webview>` themselves, it has a native menu, etc.

Is it possible to have a `<webview>` constrained so that content in windows opened from it run within a `<webview>`?

Comment: All the electron apps which I have used e.g. Nylas n1, gitkraken, atom, slack. They don't have a constrained window. e.g. Nylas N1, have a Activity window, which is independent. I have been looking for a settings window which is inside the BrowserWindow and as of now I think its just a Modal Window which can be used.

Comment: Imagine an email app (Nylas(?)). It would need to display 3rd-party HTML, the contents of emails. How to achieve that without letting that content create a `BrowserWindow`?